# plot mutiple line on the same figure using mplwidget in python(x,y)

Tags: python, matplotlib, widget, qt-designer

I was trying to plot multiple line/dots using the mplwidget in Qtdesigner plugin. Usually when i use matplotlib in python by default it will keep the first line graph and plot another graph on top of that for comparison. But in Qtdesigner,after i am using matplotlib as a widget object, i select figure object then addsubplot and then plot the graph, it seems like it will delete the old line graph and plot the new one. I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with the coding, but i'm new to this GUI stuff, i'm not sure which part of it went wrong

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from window import Ui_MainWindow
import sqlite3
import os
from datetime import datetime
import calendar
import numpy


os.chdir("C:\Data")
conn = sqlite3.connect('FBG.db')
c=conn.cursor()

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):


    def searching_database(self):
        self.ui.listWidget.clear()
        data = self.ui.Inputname.text()
        for df in c.execute("select name from sqlite_master where type='table'; "):
            strdf=str(df)
            if len(data)==0:
                break
            if strdf[3:(len(data)+3)] == data: # the name for df start from position 3 due to "[u "
            self.ui.listWidget.addItem(strdf[3:-3])
            else:
                pass

    def delete_selection(self):
        self.ui.listWidget_3.takeItem(self.ui.listWidget_3.currentRow())


    def clear_graph(self):
        self.ui.listWidget_3.clear()
        self.ax.clear()
        self.ui.mplwidget.draw()

    def plot_graph(self):
        b=self.ui.listWidget.currentItem().text()
        b=str(b)
        self.ui.listWidget_3.addItem(b)

        time1= QtCore.QDateTime(self.ui.dateTimeEdit.dateTime())
        date1 = time1.toPyDateTime()
        timestamp1 = calendar.timegm(date1.utctimetuple()) #return a integer value

        time2= QtCore.QDateTime(self.ui.dateTimeEdit_2.dateTime())
        date2 = time2.toPyDateTime()
        timestamp2 = calendar.timegm(date2.utctimetuple()) 
        time=[]
        data=[]
        for df in c.execute('''select * from '''+ b ):
            time= numpy.append(time, df[0])
            data= numpy.append(data, df[1])
        self.ax.plot([2,4,5,6],[1,5,6,7],label=b) % set up for matplot widget
        self.ax.plot([1,3,4,5],[2,4,5,6],label=b+"afasdasdasd") % set up for matplot widget
        self.ax.legend() % set up for matplot widget
        self.ui.mplwidget.draw() % set up for matplot widget
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.Inputname.textChanged.connect(self.searching_database)
        self.ui.listWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.plot_graph)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.plot_graph)
        self.ui.Delete.clicked.connect(self.delete_selection)
        self.ui.Clear.clicked.connect(self.clear_graph)
        self.ui.mplwidget.axes.set_title("Strain/Temperature vs Time") % set up for matplot widget
        self.fig = self.ui.mplwidget.figure % set up for matplot widget
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) % set up for matplot widget
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window= Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The code is running fine. But i think there must be some code prevent me getting what i am trying to achieve. I think it might those codes with "% set up for matplot widget" following them. Any suggestions would be good.

Comment: There is non-valid python in your code.  `#` in the comment marker not `%`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

class myWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

        self.plotCurve(self.canvas)


    def plotCurve(self, FigureCanvas):
        left, width = 0.1, 0.8
        rect1 = [left, 0.2, width, 0.6]

        FigureCanvas.figure.set_facecolor('white')
        axescolor  = '#f6f6f6'  # the axies background color
        FigureCanvas.figure.clear()
        ax1 = FigureCanvas.figure.add_axes(rect1, axisbg=axescolor)  #left, bottom, width, height

        ax1.set_title('Some Curve')

        x = range(10, 20)
        y = range(10, 20)
        z = range(20, 30)

        p1, = ax1.plot(x, y, 'ro')
        p2, = ax1.plot(x, z, '-')

        ax1.set_ylabel('Some Label')

        FigureCanvas.draw()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = myWidget()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.ui.mplwidget.axes.hold(True)
```

This should let you plot two data sets on the same axis, just like you can in interactive mode. Worked for me!